# Angular refreshes parent route when it doesn't change

Tags: angular

```js
// Routes for a lazy loaded module routed on `/management/`
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
  { path: 'user/:id', component: UserDetailComponent },
  { path: 'productUserScope/:id', component: ProdUserScopeComponent },
  { path: 'organisation/:id', component: OrganisationDetailComponent },
  {
    path: '',
// A component with 3 tabs linked to components in child routes.
    component: ManagementComponent,
    children: [
// child components for each tab rendered via the router-outlet.
      { path: 'users', component: UserListComponent },
      { path: 'productUserScopes', component: OrganisationProductScopeListComponent },
      { path: 'organisations', component: OrganisationListComponent },
    ],
  },
];
```

When I'm on `/management/users` and then I navigate to `/management/organisations` (Ie another tab) the `ngOnInit` function on the parent component `ManagementComponent` is called again meaning the page is refreshed even though the parent hasn't changed.

Any idea how to fix this issue? I've tried changing to a relative path with no difference.

Wondering if it's to do with the way the routes are defined. The problem is I don't want the detail / id pages to showing the tabs which are in the `ManagementComponent`.